# ¿Como validad el success:function() de una funcion Ajax para un sistema de Login?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Tengo problemas para validar un formulario con AJAX y JQuery, no se como hacer el Success.function() Y que de el formulario sea validado con las variables que son, he intentado colocando valores True y False con la funcion mysqli_query pero no funcionaba, basicamente, siempre se ejecuta el ELSE del if o siempre se ejecuta el IF. A continuación los codigos, espero que me puedan ayudar, es un proyecto al cual el tengo muchas esperanzas
-La idea es que la variable (r) del success pueda funcionar correctamente-
Codigo HTML del Formulario con sus respectivos campos y boton:

```
<form id="loginCredentials" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="login" value="Ingresar" name="login" form="loginCredentials">
```

Codigo JQuery con Ajax:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#login').click(function(){
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        if($.trim(username).length > 0 && $.trim(password).length > 0){
          $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"./php/loginCredentials.php",
            data:{username:username, password:password},
            cache:"false",
            beforeSend:function(){
              $('#login').val("Conectando...");
            },
            success:function(r){
              if(r == 1){
                alert ("Puto success");
                $(location).attr('href', './indexUser.php');
              } else {
                alert ("Puto error");
                $("#result").html("<div class='alert alert-dismissible alert-danger'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><strong>¡Error!</strong> Las credenciales son erroneas.</div>");
                $('#login').val("Ingresar");
              }
            }
          });
        } else {
          $("#result").html("<div class='alert alert-dismissible alert-danger'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><strong>¡Error!</strong> Digite un usuario y contraseña</div>");
          $('#login').val("Ingresar");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Codigo del archivo PHP para validar:

```
<?php

    include"conexion.php";  
    if ($_POST) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where user='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $result = $conexion->query($sql);
        if ($result == 1) {
            $value = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $value['username'];
            echo "1";
        } else {
            echo "error";
        }
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Haz una prueba de la respuesta: `console.log(r);`  activa la consola para verla y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: ¿En que parte del codigo coloco la linea de codigo?, la coloqué justo debajo del success y esto aparece en consola: 
<b>Notice</b>:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Carrito\php\loginCredentials.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: username in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Carrito\php\loginCredentials.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />

Comment: OK, cambia esto: `if ($result == 1) {` por esto: **`if ($result) {`** en el código PHP, pues `$result` es un recurso y ahí interpeta que lo quieres convertir a entero. Además, parece que los datos no están llegando, porque dice *Undefined username*

Comment: Probablemente deberás quitarle el `cache:"false",` a la petición Ajax.

Comment: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: username in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Carrito\php\loginCredentials.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
1

Comment: Está vez apareció lo anterior siguiento tus pasos

Comment: `Undefined index: username` significa que `data` no está llegando. ¿Le quitaste esto a la petición Ajax: `cache:"false",`?

Comment: El parámetro `cache` debe usarse solamente en este caso según la documentación: *The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.*  Si eso no se cumple debes quitarlo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105596/discussion-between-giovanni-mosquera-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en tu archivo php, ya que la variable $result solo está ejecutando la consulta ( $conexion->query($sql) ).
Para validar correctamente debes contar los campos con una función una vez realizada la consulta.

Te dejo tu código antiguo y el nuevo, prueba y nos avisas !

```
<?php

    include"conexion.php";  
    if ($_POST) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where user='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $result = $conexion->query($sql);
        if ($result == 1) {
            $value = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $value['username'];
            echo "1";
        } else {
            echo "error";
        }
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }

?>
```

Nuevo:

```
<?php

    include"conexion.php";  
    if ($_POST) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where user='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $result = $conexion->query($sql);
        //declaramos la variable rows que gracias a la función num_rows nos devolverá el número de filas de la consulta.
//si el usuario y la clave son idénticas a las de la base de datos num_rows nos devolverá como número 1 y si no encuentra nada o el usuario se equivoco al escribir un dato, devuelve 0
        $rows = $result->num_rows;
        if ($rows == 1) {
            $value = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $value['username'];
            echo "1";
        } else {
            echo "error";
        }
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }

?>
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función de `error` para capturar cualquier error, y dar un código de respuesta **500** de parte del php

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    var msg = '';
    if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        msg = 'No encontrado';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
        msg = 'Error ejecutando';
    }
    console.log(msg);
}
```

Entonces cuando tu php responde con error, tambíen puedes cambiar el código de respuesta y enviar un mensaje al cliente mediante AJAX.

Comment: Disculpa pero es que no entiendo muy bien, en que parte va ese codigo?

Comment: @GiovanniMosquera Despues de `succes: function()` , es otra función de ajax a parte de  **success**

Comment: Disculpa... Pero no entiendo en que parte  exactamente, estuve colocandolo en varias partes y queda sin funcionar el button